# Remove duplicate characters using a regular expression

Tags: .net, regex

I need to Match the second and subsequent occurances of the * character using a regular expression.  I'm actually using the Replace method to remove them so here's some examples of before and after:

```
test*     ->  test* (no change)
*test*    ->  *test
test** *e ->  test* e
```

Is it possible to do this with a regular expression?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If .NET can cope with an arbitrary amount of look behind, try replacing the following pattern with an empty string:

```
(?<=\*.*)\*
```

.

```
PS Home:\> 'test*','*test*','test** *e' -replace '(?<=\*.*)\*',''
test*
*test
test* e
```

Another way would be this pattern:

```
(?<=\*.{0,100})\*
```

where the number `100` can be replaced with the size of the target string.

And testing the following with Mono 2.0:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<=\*.*)\*");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", r.Replace("test*", ""));    
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", r.Replace("*test*", ""));    
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", r.Replace("test** *e", ""));                          
    }
}
```

also produced:

```
test*
*test
test* e
```

Comment: The first one works in .NET 4.  I've notteste it in a prior version.

Comment: Added a PowerShell proof of concept; the first one does work.

Comment: @Johannes, cheers. Does PowerShell use the same regex engine? (is PowerShell written in .NET?)

Comment: Yes, PowerShell is written in .NET; and since you also have access to the complete .NET framework it makes a pretty nice playground for quickly testing something, such as regular expressions and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Non optimal, but another approach.
Record the index of the first occurrence, replace all occurrence, and reinsert the first occurrence at the recored index.

Comment: Ah well, all the looking behind when using regex will be far less optimal! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str =~ s/\*/MYSPECIAL/;  #only replace the first *
$str =~ s/\*//g;          #replace all *
$str =~ s/MYSPECIAL/\*/;  #put * back
```

Comment: What .NET language is that? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Looks like Perl to me.